# Why can't my bpmn xml file be displayed correctly in Eclipse BPMN2 Modeler?

Tags: eclipse, bpmn

I programmatically generated an XML format .bpmn file with no BPMN Diagram elements. I want to use Eclipse BPMN2 Modeler to generate the diagram elements automatically for me. But when I open the file using the Eclipse Bpmn2 Diagram Editor, it only shows me empty pools with nothing in it. I cannot see any detail of my processes.

Could anyone tell me why it is so and how to fix the problem to make it display all the information of my processes?

Due to character number limit, I cannot paste my bpmn file here

Below is the link for you to download my original bpmn xml file and the wrongly generated picture:

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1_A_UydpVTsUYPbZT0zHazegLVc4ihGbI?usp=sharing

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your BPMN is **not valid**.
I tried to load it into an **online BPMN editor** at  **https://demo.bpmn.io/**
, But below is the error.

[image]

I suggest to validate your BPMN **manually** or try to add some tasks to your process and re-try.

**Update:**

As per the [**official docs**](https://www.eclipse.org/bpmn2-modeler/documentation/BPMN2ModelerUserGuide-1.0.1.pdf) of Eclipse BPMN2 Modeler, **this feature is NOT stable.**

> BPMN2 Modeler has the ability to import files that do not contain DI
>   metadata and will generate it using an auto layout algorithm. This
>   algorithm is **still in the experimental phase** as of this version – it
>   does a fair, but not optimal job of arranging the business logic
>   elements. If, after importing such a BPMN file, any elements that
>   appear “out of place” or not optimally placed can simply be dragged
>   around on the canvas for more visually pleasing configurations. Once
>   these changes have been saved, the DI metadata is added to the file
>   and the new layout is restored next time the file is opened.

Comment: Yes this BPMN is considered invalid because it does not have BPMN Diagram Elements (i.e. DI information) and that is why your online editor got errors. I mentioned this in my post. The reason why I opened it in Eclipse BPMN2 Modeler is to have the modeler to generate the DI information for me automatically. Eclipse BPMN2 Modeler has this functionality.

Comment: What I get confused about is that the modeler only generate the pools for me, no information about other elements like tasks gateways and flows in the bpmn file. I find that if the bpmn file contains no collaboration related elements like <collaboration> and <participant>, it  can be well displayed. So, I don't know why it cannot be displayed correctly once I add those collaboration elements.